# Как получить peer_id?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Как получить `peer_id` в этом коде ?

```py
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='***')
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, '***')
vk = vk_session.get_api()

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:

        vk.messages.send(peer_id = event.peer_id, message='привет', random_id=0)
```

в данном коде выдаёт ошибку

```
AttributeError: 'VkBotMessageEvent' object has no attribute 'peer_id'
```

Comment: peer_id = event.peer_id - не оно, разве?

Comment: выдаёт ошибку
AttributeError: 'VkBotMessageEvent' object has no attribute 'peer_id'

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `event.peer_id` на `event.object.peer_id`

Comment: Пытался, в консоле пишет следующее:

`vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [100] One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: you should specify peer_id, user_id, domain, chat_id or user_ids param`

Comment: А если заменить на `event.chat_id`?

Comment: с ней всё нормально работает, но мне нужно что бы он и с лс и с беседой работал

Comment: А если `event.obj.peer_id`  или  `event.message.peer_id`?

Comment: `event.message.peer_id` работает)